# Release Queued Laravel Job without increasing Attempts count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

Sometimes I need to release a Laravel job and have it rejoin the queue. However when doing this, the attempts count is increased. It becomes 2 and, if  your queue worker is limited to 1 try, it will never be run.

How can I release without increasing attempts?

To release I am using:

```
$this->release(30);
```

Prior to this line I have tried the following code:

```
$payload = json_decode($this->payload, true);
if (isset($payload['attempts'])) {
    $payload['attempts'] = 0;
}
$this->payload = json_encode($payload);
```

This does not work. The `payload` property is not available. It seems to be present in [the Job class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php#L98).

The code Laravel framework has to reset count is in the `RetryCommand` class. It is as follows:

```
protected function resetAttempts($payload)
{
    $payload = json_decode($payload, true);
    if (isset($payload['attempts'])) {
        $payload['attempts'] = 0;
    }
    return json_encode($payload);
}
```

But I cannot work out how to access the `$payload` from my job class?

Is there a better way to release a job without increasing the attempt count?

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Redis queue driver.

Answer (score 4):

So I just ended up deleting and requeuing a new job. Maybe not clean but it does work.

```
$this->delete();

$job = (new ProcessPage($this->pdf))->onQueue('converting');
dispatch($job);
```